# Drop down animation positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to make the drop down that appears when you hover over one of the four thumbnails, drop down from underneath where it says 'Caption Title' rather than the top of the image.

I've been fiddling around with the CSS but with no luck and since I have hardly any JS experience I don't know if it's the JS that needs editing and not the CSS!

Yuu can find the CSS at the very bottom of style.css

I reckon this is probably a quick and easy question for people on here!

http://www.jimharrison.co.uk/

Also while I'm here I may as well ask if anyone knows a better way for animating the moving image - I'm currently using CSS3 @keyframes but it's a tad choppy in some browsers.

```
<div class="grid-block-container">
<div class="grid-block slide">
<div class="caption1">
<h3>Caption Title</h3>
</div>
<div class="caption">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
<p><a href="#" class="learn-more">Learn more</a></p>
</div>
<img src="img/1.jpg" alt="nebula">
</div>
</div>

.grid-block-container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.grid-block {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.caption1 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(246,48,62,0.7);
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.caption {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(246,48,62,0.7);
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.caption1 h3, .caption p {
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 20px;
}

.caption1 h3 {
    margin: 20px 20px 10px;
}

.caption p {
    font-size: .9em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin: 0 20px 15px;
}

.caption a.learn-more {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #f6303e;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.caption a.learn-more:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #f6303e;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.standard').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').show();
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').hide();
        }
    );
    $('.fade').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').fadeIn(250);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').fadeOut(250);
        }
    );
    $('.slide').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').slideDown(200);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(200);
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8j63s/

Comment: JSfiddle please and HTML/CSS in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `CSS` to show this:

```
.caption {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 71px;
left: 0;
background: rgba(246,48,62,0.7);
width: 100%;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

That drops it underneath the caption title if the caption title is only on one line. See screenshot below:
[image]

To have it so that it does the change dynamically, you will need to change the `jQuery` a bit to work across all of them with this piece of code:

```
$('.slide').each(function() {
    var titleHeight = $(this).find('.caption1').innerHeight();
    $(this).find('.caption').css('top', titleHeight + 'px');
});
```

That will go through each element that is in a class named slide, get the title height and then change the caption text to fit under it.

Comment: Incredibly fast replies as usual such a great community!

I tried applying the 71px to top but unfortunately no luck. HOwever, I'm all for improving upon what I've done so I'll try the latter method also

EDIT: Scrap that it worked perfectly! Now to try the JS method :)

Comment: Absolutely perfect thanks. Works like a dream! Got the JS part working with the variable height. Prime stuff cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the .caption div to the following

```
.caption {display: none; position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; background:rgba(246,48,62,0.7); width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff; padding-bottom: 15px; }
```

All this does is remove the top:0; style to bottom:0;

See screenshot below:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

could work only with css (davidb answer) but if you want a jquery version you could do:

```
$('.grid-block').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.caption').slideDown();
},function(){
    $(this).find('.caption').slideUp();
});
```

also change `.caption` style `top` to `bottom`:0;

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PJkgd/)